# How to use blktrace to monitor the eMMC Flash access pattern?

Tags: linux, performance, block-device, flash-memory

I'm trying to simulate a FTL(Flash Translation Layer) algorithm and evaluate its performance. What I need is a trace file of a flash access(containing information about block and page access).
I'm trying to capture the flash access pattern from an embedded board that has a 4GB eMMC flash on it.
A friend suggested me to use blktrace tool. but there is no /dev/sda file on this system.how should I use blktrace to capture flash access on this system?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you wish to track but all access from kernel to device (SPI interface or whatever) - except initial detection after plugging it in - goes through /dev as far as I know.

Comment: @ned64 I need a sequence of logical addresses(logical block plus  logical page) that have been accessed.

Comment: It depends on your setup just exactly where this data is generated, and you need to examine that.  For example, what is the physical interface to your flash memory (like SPI), what layers (if any) are between the kernel and this interface, and can you access the data.  You may need debug functionality of the kernel itself to assess access data by the kernel on the driver level.